# CSS Input field not responsive

Tags: css

I am at wits end and could really use some help.  I am trying to create an input field, in this case "PASSWORD" that is flexible in that when the screen resizes, so does the field and data, but it doesn't work.  I see 2 problems:

1:  It only allows something like 17 characters and then trails into nothing.  What I want is after you lose focus on the field, the field populates with the "..." ( text-overflow: ellipsis ) if it is bigger than field itself.

2. Allow more than just the 17 characters at input time.  If I use a percentage, like 80%, when the screen resizes, it drops the field down a row, making it neither pretty nor responsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/lepew/y3jkyx1c/6/

```css
body
{
  background: #181818;
}


/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the sunken field.  It will be generic for all forms.        */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#form_Sunk
{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: repeat-x center center #000;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 1px 1px;
}

/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the gray button WITHIN the sunken field.                    */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#sunk_Knob
{
   float: left;
   color: #fff;
   height: 26px;
   background: #777;
   text-align: left;
   line-height: 26px;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: relative;
   margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
   padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
   border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the data area WITHIN the sunken field.                      */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#sunk_Data
{
   color: cyan;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 25px;
   font-weight: bold;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the Tool Tip WITHIN the sunken field.                       */
/*  LEFT is used when it is INSIDE the sunken area.                     */
/*  RIGHT is used when it is OUTSIDE the sunken area.                   */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#sunk_Tool
{
   top: -22px;
   xleft: -7px;
   right: -20px;
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   background: url("question-mark-000.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
}


/*  GOOD from HERE ^^^^^ up.  */


#peter04
{
   border: 0 none;
   color: yellow;
   padding-left: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   padding-right: 25px;
   background-color: transparent;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#sunk_Tips
{
   top: 8px;
   right: -20px;
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   background: url("question-mark-000.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
}

::-ms-clear
{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
   <div id="form_Sunk">
      <div id="sunk_Knob">
         User ID:
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Data" title="THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.">
         THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Tool" title="USER ID">
      </div>
   </div>

   <br />
   <br />

   <div id="form_Sunk">
      <div id="sunk_Knob">
         Password:
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="pword" id="peter04" placeholder="Password">
      <div id="sunk_Tips" title="PASSWORD">
      </div>
   </div>

   <br />
   <br />
   <div id="form_Sunk">
      <div id="sunk_Knob">
         Code:
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Data" title="THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.">
         THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Tool" title="CODE">
      </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
</form>  
    
</body
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use `display: flex` to get the password field to be responsive. It uses the `flex: grow` property to make the password box take up the remaining horizontal space in its container. The main CSS I added was:

```
#form_Sunk > * {
    display: block;
}

#form_Sunk input {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#sunk_Knob
{
   ...
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

You can learn more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

---

PLEASE NOTE that for your HTML to be valid, you will need to change a lot of your IDs to be classes instead, and generally rework your markup. There can only be a single element with a specific ID in an HTML document. This example is intended to show you the minimal changes needed to demonstrate positioning/sizing concepts.

**Full Live Example:**

```css
body
{
  background: #181818;
}


/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the sunken field.  It will be generic for all forms.        */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#form_Sunk
{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   display: flex;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: repeat-x center center #000;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 1px 1px;
}

#form_Sunk > * {
    display: block;
}

#form_Sunk input {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the gray button WITHIN the sunken field.                    */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#sunk_Knob
{
   float: left;
   color: #fff;
   height: 26px;
   background: #777;
   text-align: left;
   line-height: 26px;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: relative;
   margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
   padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
   border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the data area WITHIN the sunken field.                      */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#sunk_Data
{
   color: cyan;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 25px;
   font-weight: bold;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* ******************************************************************** */
/*                                                                      */
/*  This is the Tool Tip WITHIN the sunken field.                       */
/*  LEFT is used when it is INSIDE the sunken area.                     */
/*  RIGHT is used when it is OUTSIDE the sunken area.                   */
/*                                                                      */
/* ******************************************************************** */
#sunk_Tool
{
   top: -22px;
   xleft: -7px;
   right: -20px;
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   background: url("question-mark-000.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
}


/*  GOOD from HERE ^^^^^ up.  */


#peter04
{
   border: 0 none;
   color: yellow;
   padding-left: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   padding-right: 25px;
   background-color: transparent;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#sunk_Tips
{
   top: 8px;
   right: -20px;
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   background: url("question-mark-000.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
}

::-ms-clear
{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
   <div id="form_Sunk">
      <div id="sunk_Knob">
         User ID:
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Data" title="THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.">
         THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Tool" title="USER ID">
      </div>
   </div>

   <br />
   <br />

   <div id="form_Sunk">
      <div id="sunk_Knob">
         Password:
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="pword" id="peter04" placeholder="Password">
      <div id="sunk_Tips" title="PASSWORD">
      </div>
   </div>

   <br />
   <br />
   <div id="form_Sunk">
      <div id="sunk_Knob">
         Code:
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Data" title="THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.">
         THIS IS TEST CODE FOR NADA.
      </div>
      <div id="sunk_Tool" title="CODE">
      </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
</form>  
    
</body
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/y3jkyx1c/8/

Comment: Hello:Brilliant, thanks, but now another problem.  In this case, the User ID: breaks apart when it is resized.  I have tried block, inline and inline-block and all 3 don't change anything.